# Maximum deviation between two measurement methods

Tags: definition, education

I'm trying to understand what is the maximum deviation between two measurement methods. I read this on a paper on which there is a comparison between two devices to measure pH.

The sentence on the above paper is: "Maximum deviation was found to be 1.2% or 0.08 pH between two measurement methods.".

Online I found only a definition related to a single set of measurements (http://phys.columbia.edu/~tutorial/estimation/tut_e_2_3.html):

$$Maximum \,\,\, deviation=max \,\, measured \,\, value - average \,\, value$$

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case the maximum deviation *between two measurement methods* is the maximum difference of their measurements for the same input sample.

Thus if the two methods agree or nearly agree on most samples, but on one sample differ by a large value 1.2%, then the "maximum deviation between two measurement methods" is that 1.2%.

It is a simple concept.

Comment: Hello @DavidGStork, thus, if \$x_{1i}\$ is the input i of method 1 and if \$x_{2i}\$ is the input i of method 2:$$maximum \,\, deviation=max\mid x_{1i}-x_{2i} \mid$$ for i=1,...,n?

Comment: Hello @David G. Stork, thus, if $x_{1i}$ is the input i of method 1 and if $x_{2i}$ is the input i of method 2:
$$maximum \,\, deviation=max∣x1i−x2i∣$$
for i=1,...,n?